# cron golang running after every 24 Hour?

Tags: go, cron

`cron` golang is running after every 24 hours but when I am trying to change the system time, it is not invoking.

### code:

```
package main;

import(
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2"
    "time"
    )

func Envoke_ASSET_INFO() {    
    fmt.Println("Invoking Envoke_ASSET_INFO ", time.Now())
}

func main(){
    C:=cron.New()

    min:=strconv.Itoa(int(17))
    h:=strconv.Itoa(int(16))

    sep:="0"+" "+min+" "+h+" "+"*"+" "+"*"+" "+"*"
    fmt.Println("SPECIFATION PASSED TO FUNCTION :", sep)    
    C.AddFunc(sep, Envoke_ASSET_INFO )
    C.Start()
    select{}
}
```

When I am running this program it is evoking my function. But when I change my system time (+24 hours) to check the next evoking it is not happening.

Comment: Functions that use time durations are monotonic, and you can't speed them up by changing the system time (which can always cause other unexpected problems). If the program is in a timer or sleep, it has no way of knowing that the system time changed.

Comment: does i am doing any thing wrong ,or it will work fine in production ,I am doing right or not the SPECIFICATION i am passing to ADDFUN is correct or not .

Comment: perhaps you could refer to this minimalist cron go-package: https://github.com/roylee0704/gron

Answer (score 5):

This is not how cron works. Cron won't run overdue tasks when you change system time. Think what would happen if it worked that way and you turned your machine on after 2 days with job scheduled to run every 5 minutes. If you really want to test it that way you should change the system time to a time just before your job is supposed to run and wait to see if it does.

Personally I think that it's a better idea to pass hour and minute as parameters and check if the job is running on next minute or something.

Comment: i Overcome with that problem by just adding another job which run frequently ,like every 2min or 5 min, then  after changing system time i am able to  test jobs after 24H,48H,72H etc.